# How to group my indexes in my timeseries data?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, time-series

Beginner coder here...

I'm trying to get the mean data for every year. The resample seems to not work, what is the problem?

```
data=pd.read_csv('Water well.csv', parse_dates=["datetime"],index_col="datetime")`
```

[image]

```
data1=data.resample('1y', on='datetime').mean().reset_index()
data1
```

KeyError: 'The grouper name datetime is not found'

https://www.waterdatafortexas.org/groundwater/well/8739308
The data comes from here

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to provide a value for parameter 'on' if you want to group by the index column.
It is mentioned in the Pandas documentation for resample method:

> on str, optional
> For a DataFrame, column to use instead of index for resampling. Column must be datetime-like.

(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

The following will work:

```
data1=data.resample('1y').mean().reset_index()
```

However, you should consider which columns you need to be present in the grouped results.
You may get unexpected results if your dataframe contains non-numeric columns.

What is the purpose of using reset_index()? In your case, it will change the DateTimeIndex with frequency to RangeIndex of integers.

Without reset_index():

```
>>> data2=data['water_level(ft below land surface)'].resample('1y').mean()
>>> data2.index
DatetimeIndex(['2016-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2018-12-31', '2019-12-31',
               '2020-12-31', '2021-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', freq='A-DEC')
>>> data2
datetime
2016-12-31    28.082380
2017-12-31    28.553674
2018-12-31    27.897536
2019-12-31    26.807835
2020-12-31    27.973135
2021-12-31    27.331749
```

With reset_index():

```
>>> data3=data['water_level(ft below land surface)'].resample('1y').mean().reset_index()
>>> data3.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=6, step=1)
>>> data3
    datetime  water_level(ft below land surface)
0 2016-12-31                           28.082380
1 2017-12-31                           28.553674
2 2018-12-31                           27.897536
3 2019-12-31                           26.807835
4 2020-12-31                           27.973135
5 2021-12-31                           27.331749
```

Comment: Thank you! @nelyanne